# Would f ''(a)=0 and f ''(x) does not change sign at x=a result in an inflection point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My note says: " If f ''(a)=0  and f ''(x) changes sign at x=a, there is a point of inflection at (a, f(a))."

I was wondering how the original graph would appear if f ''(a)=0  and f ''(x) does not change sign at x=a, would there still be a point of inflection?

Comment: If $f''$ does not change sign, no inflection point occurs. Just like how, if $f'(a)=0$ but $f'$ doesn't change sign at $x=a$, $f$ does not have a relative extremum at $x=a$.

Comment: My note also says that a point of inflection occurs where f''(x) is undefined but how is this possible?

Comment: [Here's how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, note that we use MathJax here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider for example $f(x)=x^4$ at the origin

[image]

and compare with $f(x)=x^3$ at the origin.

Comment: I don't think a quartic function can have an inflection point because it never changes concavity

Comment: @Timmy Yes indeed it is a simple example of what occurs if $f''(0)=0$ but $f''$ doesn't change sign at $x=0$. Maybe you are looking for something else?

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks. I was also wondering how a point of inflection can occur where f''(x) is undefined.

Comment: @Timmy Yes think to $x^\frac13$ https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljk9m.png the slope at 0 is vertical and it is an inflection point thus f'(x) and f''(x) are undefined.

Comment: That makes sense. Also, I know that f '(x) is undefined at cusps, vertical tangents  and at discontinuities, so f''(x) will always be undefined when f'(x) is undefined. Is there a scenario where f(x) has an inflection point when f '(x) is defined and f''(x) is undefined?

Comment: @Timmy yes of course $f(x)=x^2 for x\ge0$ and $=-x^2 for x<0$ should be of this kind.

Comment: the graphs of the equations are parobolas so i see that f'(x) exists and f''(x) does not exist but i do not see the inflection point, where does the graph change concavity?

Comment: @Timmy $x^2$ is convex and $-x^2$ is concave and f'(x)=2|x| exists while $f''(x)$ in undefined in $0$